# Several concept questions about AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm preparing for AWS Certificate Associate. Have some concept questions about AWS VPC.

1. For Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI), the main text in the study guide says and I quote:

> It’s possible to attach additional ENIs to an instance. **Those ENIs may be in a different
> subnet, but they must be in the same availability zone as the instance.** *As always, any
> addresses associated with the ENI must come from the subnet to which it is attached.*

while in the summary of this chapter, still in study guide says:

> Any
> additional ENI you attach to an instance **must be in the same subnet** as the primary ENI.

1.1 Are the bold parts in the above two statements contradictory? Because one says ENIs should be in the same subset while the other says in the same AZ, which one is right?

1.2 How to interpret the relationship between the bold part and the italic part in the first statement? Is it like the ENI can be **located** in other subnets, but the address should point to the instance that it has been **attached to**? Sounds kind of weird.

2. About difference between NAT Gateway and NAT Instance.
   The book states NAT Instance can connect to instances that don't have public IP, while NAT Gateway cannot. Just want to clarify, does this "instance" means the **destination instance in the Internet**, instead of the **sourcing instance within VPC**? Since the reason to adopt NAT devices (no matter gateway or instance) is because the sourcing instance in private cloud doesn't have public IP?
   Thanks!

Comment: Reddit is good place for aws cert info and questions: https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/

Answer (score 3):

An instance *can* have multiple ENIs, each in a different subnet (within the same Availability Zone). I recommend that you try it yourself to confirm. In fact, that is good advice for *everything* you do in AWS because the Certification is meant to prove that you have the knowledge and experience (rather than just having read a Study Guide).

All you'll need to know about NAT in a VPC is:

- A **NAT Gateway** is a managed service that resides in a single subnet and AZ. An Elastic IP address is assigned to the NAT Gateway and all traffic coming from it to the Internet will 'appear' to be coming from that Elastic IP address.
- A **NAT Instance** is an EC2 instance configured as a NAT. It can be assigned an Elastic IP address, or a normal (random) public IP address.

Again, I highly recommend you create both types, then configure and use them in a VPC. That way, you are actually increasing your own knowledge that would be useful for a future employer (rather than just getting a certification).